# Curl Issue NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)

Tags: curl, networking, installation, k3s

**I am trying to install k3s in my virtual machine. while downloading it gets stuck here**....

#curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_VERSION=v1.18.9+k3s1 sh -s - server --datastore-endpoint="mysql://user:password@tcp(x.x.x.x:3306)/database_name"

#[INFO]  Using v1.18.9+k3s1 as release

[INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.9+k3s1/sha256sum-amd64.txt

**While curl i get following**

# curl -v https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.9+k3s1/sha256sum-amd64.txt

- About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
- Trying 20.205.243.166...
- Connected to github.com (20.205.243.166) port 443 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
- TCP connection reset by peer
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer

**I am using**

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download the file with wget ... looks like the web server is re-directing the link... use curl with the -L switch to follow the link:

```
curl -L  https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.9+k3s1/sha256sum-amd64.txt
```